# Beamer: How to make an environment which is like "altenv"

Tags: beamer, overlays

Reading Section 9.6.3 of the `beamer` book, I try to make a new environment which should behave just like `alertenv` but with different visual effects. 
Here is the code I use for testing this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment<>{itenv}{\mdseries\itshape}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\begin{frame}{With \texttt{alertenv}}
before items
  \pause
  \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{itemize}
\pause
after items
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{With \texttt{itenv}}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
before items
  \pause
  \begin{itemize}[<+- | it@+>]
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
  \end{itemize}
\pause
after items
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As it turns out, if an overlayed frame uses `altenv`, the current item changes
to `alert` mode, i.e., painted in red. This item changes its color back to black, as the slide number progresses.

On the other hand, if the same overlayed frame uses `itenv`, the current item changes
to italics. Butt, it does not changes back to non-italics as the slide number progresses.

[image: animation showing frames in sequence]

What am I doing wrong here?

### Same Example: More Details

The following is a more verbose version of the example above. If someone cares to solve this problem, it might be used to demonstrate the solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment<>{itenv}{\only{\mdseries\itshape}}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{frame}{With \texttt{alertenv}}
    before items
    \pause
    \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{first}, and then return to be black. 
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{second}, and then return to be black. 
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{third}, and then return to be black. 
    \end{itemize}
    \pause
    after items
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{With \texttt{itenv}}
    before items
    \pause
    \begin{itemize}[<+- | it@+>]
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{first}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Take a close look. Did I return to be ``\textup{Up Shape}''?
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{second}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Ditto. 
      Am I ``\textup{Up Shape}'' or ``\textit{Italicized Shape}''?
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{third}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Did I return to be ``\textup{Up Shape}'' or am I ``\textit{Italicized Shape}''?
    \end{itemize}
    \pause
    after items
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here is a little animation that demonstrates the problem with my code.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to insert the `\begin{altenv}...\end{altenv}` into the `newenvironment` definition as displayed below

```
\newenvironment<>{itenv}{%
\begin{altenv}#1
{\mdseries\itshape}
{}{}{}}
{\end{altenv}}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment<>{itenv}{%
\begin{altenv}#1{\mdseries\itshape}
{}{}{}}
{\end{altenv}}

\begin{frame}{With \texttt{alertenv}}
    before items
    \pause
    \begin{itemize}[<+- | alert@+>]
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{first}, and then return to be black. 
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{second}, and then return to be black. 
        \item I will be \textcolor{red}{red} \textbf{third}, and then return to be black. 
    \end{itemize}
    \pause
    after items
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{With \texttt{itenv}}
    before items
    \pause
    \begin{itemize}[<+- | it@+>]
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{first}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Take a close look. Did I return to be ``\textup{Up Shape}''?
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{second}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Ditto. 
      Am I ``\textup{Up Shape}'' or ``\textit{Italicized Shape}''?
        \item I should be \textit{italicized} \textbf{third}, and then return to be up shaped. 
      Did I return to be ``\textup{Up Shape}'' or am I ``\textit{Italicized Shape}''?
    \end{itemize}
    \pause
    after items
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```